# How to display just video post format?

Tags: loop, tax-query

I actually stuck to display a 'video' post format in the video section on main page. Here is my current code:

```
<?php

                // The Query
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 
                      'posts_per_page' => 4,
                      'tax_query' => array(
                            array(                
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array('post-format-video'),
                                'operator' => 'IN'
                            )
                        )
                ) );


                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                            get_template_part( 'template/loop', 'video' );
                           endwhile; 
                          wp_reset_postdata();
           else : ?>
           <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
           <?php endif; ?>
```

That code did not work. Anyone can advise? Thanks!

Comment: What is in template/loop ? You're doing the query, and then getting a template part that may be calling another loop? Or perhaps it's not using  `$query->` to access the post object values it is trying to echo?

Comment: To test, replace get_template_part() with `<span class="the_article">  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>` and see if you get linked titles.

Comment: Hey @hwl thanks! Actually the code works, just I'm not update my local host. :)

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Post what you did to solve it for other users, and you can close the question. :)